# With Prisma, How can we add a comment for a Type?

Tags: schema, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

With prisma.io (graphQl), we have:

- File: `datamodel.graphql`

```
"""I am a great User"""
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  email: String! @unique
}
```

after doing `prisma deploy`, it generates a file without the comment from the file `datamodel.graphql`

- File `generated-schema.graphql`

```
type User implements Node {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
}
```

- In the prisma `playground`, I do not have the comment.
  [image]

**How can we add a comment for a Type in order to generate a documentation in playground?**

Workaround:

If I cheat and add a comment in the `generated-schema.graphql` (this file will be overridden after the next `prisma deploy`)

`"""I am a great User"""
type User implements Node {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
}`

we have: 
[image]

Related topics:

- https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground/issues/819
- https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/getting-prisma-comments-descriptions-to-appear-in-graphql-playground-schema/2980
- https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here: 
https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/comments-in-prisma-graphql-from-datamodel-graphql/4330/2?u=alan345

`Currently, there’s no easy way to resolve this. This is an open feature request, which you can learn more about here:` https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2152

Answer (score 1):

Tools like [Nexus](https://nexus.js.org/) allow for it. Optional descriptions could be included along with types and individual fields.

[Ref to docs](https://nexus.js.org/docs/database-access-with-prisma#optional)

Comment: Looks like the links are broken or the docs moved?